# Getting ng-option text inside html

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

My Code:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.result as item.name for item in items"></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.items = [{'name': 'Yes', 'result': true },{ 'name': 'No', 'result': false }];
```

I want to display Yes and No in the select box whereas I have to send true and false to the server when Yes or No is selected respectively.

I have another div where I have to display the option text (ie Yes or No (selected one) ). I used {{selectedItem.label}} but it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Sajeetharan's answer and updated it to meet your requirement.
Following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
<title>To Do List</title>
<link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
    <select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.result as selection.name for selection in items"></select>
    <div>
        <h1> Selected one is : {{currentSelected? "Yes": (currentSelected == null)? "":"No"}} </h1>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

        app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
        function($scope) {

            $scope.items = [{'name': 'Yes', 'result': true },{ 'name': 'No', 'result': false }];
        }
        ]);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't get a way to reference back to the selection names as when the option is set, it only has what is displayed, selection.name and value as selection.result. But ng-model will only contain value. Hence added ternary operator in the expression, which is supported by expressions.

Comment: Note: I don't know how to format the code like Sajeetharan has done. So sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks the ternery operator you used helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    
   $scope.items = [{'name': 'Yes', 'result': true },{ 'name': 'No', 'result': false }];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.result as selection.name for selection in items"></select>
  <div>
    <h1> Selected one is : {{currentSelected}} </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In HTML I want "Yes" or "No"  in this section  <h1> Selected one is : {{currentSelected}} </h1>. Now if we change the select box we are getting true or false in that section.

Comment: it depends on what you need. change it as ng-options="selection.name as selection.name

Comment: I want to display Yes or No in front end whereas I have to send true or false to the server based on the selection

Answer (score 0):

Use directive to get the desired result of displaying the selected item name value but send the result value to backend.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("myctrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
      'name': 'Yes',
      'result': true
    }, {
      'name': 'No',
      'result': false
    }];
  }
]);

app.filter('getvalue', function() {

  return function(value, array) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      var selectedOption = array.filter(function(l) {
        if (l.result == value) {
          return l;
        }
      })[0];
      return selectedOption["name"];
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.result as selection.name for selection in items"></select>
  <div>
    Displayed Text : {{currentSelected | getvalue:items}} 
  </div>
  
   <div>
     Value which will be send : {{currentSelected}} 
  </div>
  
   
  
</body>
```